# search xml column inside large table (7 million rows)

Tags: sql-server, xml

Database design:

Table Name : Plays ( 6 million records)

Columns: Play id, col1, col2......col7, PlayFieldValues

PlayFieldValues xml column. sample xml stored in this column

```
<PlayAttributes>
  <PlayFields>
    <PlayField ID="Play.GenericInt1" >25</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="X" TS="">0</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="Y" >OFF</PlayField>
  </PlayFields>
</PlayAttributes>
```

Each xml has more than 25 elements

Using following query I am returning all Playid's from plays table having "Play.GenericInt1" attribute value 25 (​we can add more conditions in where clause. This is just an example.)

```
Select 

playId
FROM
(
SELECT playId, x.v.value('@ID[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS playfield ,
x.v.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS playfieldvalue
from plays
cross apply PlayFieldValues.nodes('/PlayAttributes/PlayFields/PlayField') x(v)
)T

where
T.playfield in('Play.GenericInt1') and T.playfieldvalue=25
```

Problem: This query is working great on plays table with 1k or 2k rows, but it is not scaling when running on 5 million rows table. execution time is crossing 20 min. Please advice what types of methods and procedures in sql I can use to search the xml column. I tried XML indexes but it costing us lot of space and maintenance problems.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Have you tried [selective XML indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670108.aspx)? Have you considered materializing the pieces you're after at insert/update time, with a trigger, or with a background job?

Comment: sql server 2008 and sql server 2012.     What is materializing the pieces  means? please explain. no I havent tried selective indexes. I am researching now. Thanks.

Comment: Materializing means storing a copy somewhere. So instead of extracting `playfield` from the XML at query time, you do that at insert/update time, and store the result somewhere.

Comment: for new rows we thought of doing  materializing , and store the xml in another table in linear form. but converting current 6 million rows is huge task and performance issue.

Comment: You can do 6 million rows once each, and perform that as a background task and in chunks, or you can do the above for all 6 million rows *every time you run a query*.

Comment: we are exploring that design concept. only concern is storing same data that causes repetition of data in database.

Comment: Yes, it's a trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

You may improve your performance by using xml exist, instead of extracting the values.

```
SELECT playId
from plays
where PlayFieldValues.exist('/PlayAttributes/PlayFields/PlayField[@ID = "Play.GenericInt1" and text()="25"]')=1
```

...but without any xml indexes this is still going to involve a table scan.

Comment: Thanks Mister, Appreciate your input. I am researching about xml indexes.

Comment: I would spend more time investigating materialising the values, xml indexes are not that great actually.

Comment: materialising the values is good idea for new rows, but we are researching what to do with existing 6 million rows. any ideas?

Comment: Create Views over XML Columns, do you think I can try this? Please advice

Comment: I don't believe you can create an indexed view on an XML column, and just having a view defined would not impact performance for this use case in any way.

Comment: As Aaron said in his comments, you can chunk through this table and extract the values to store them somewhere once, or you can do it every time you query it, the choice is yours, but I would personally look at a redesign.